# Two citations from the same author in one \citep, author's name not output twice

Tags: natbib

Hi and thanks for reading

small example file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}


\citep{norman_minimal_2012, norman_basic_2012-1}
\citep{flexner_medical_1910,flexner_medical_1912}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\bibliography{../caw}

\end{document}
```

the BibTex run gives two warnings:

> Warning--there's a number but no series in flexner_medical_1910
>
> Warning--there's a number but no series in flexner_medical_1912

the output is:

> (Norman et al., 2012; Norman, 2012), (Flexner, 1910, 1912)

followed by the references, which are OK.

I would have expected to see `(Flexner, 1910; Flexner 1912)` - but saw `(Flexner, 1910, 1912)`

I'd be very grateful for any pointers!

the bib entries for the flexner entries are:

```
@book{flexner_medical_1910,

    Author = {Flexner, Abraham},
    Number = {4},
    Publisher = {Carnegie Foundation for the Advancement of Teaching},
    Title = {Medical education in the United States and Canada: a report to the Carnegie Foundation for the Advancement of Teaching},
    Year = {1910}}

@book{flexner_medical_1912,

    Author = {Flexner, Abraham},
    Number = {6},
    Publisher = {Carnegie Foundation for the Advancement of Teaching},
    Title = {Medical education in Europe: a report to the Carnegie Foundation for the Advancement of Teaching},
    Year = {1912}}
```

Comment: From manual, `If adjacent citations have the same
author designation but different years, then the author names are not
reprinted.`. Hence the output is expected. If you change the names, then they appear.

Comment: thank you for your patience with a newbie - much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

As Harish has already pointed out in a comment, sorting and compression of authoryear citation call-outs is the default operation of the `natbib` package -- and is, pretty much, a global standard when working with authoryear-style citation call-outs.

The `natbib` package doesn't seem to provide options to override this default setting. If you  must create (or insist on creating) two entirely separate citation call-outs, you may do so with the instructions

```
(\citealp{flexner_medical_1910}; \citealp{flexner_medical_1912})
```

i.e., by providing two separate citation commands. (The `\citealp` instruction works just like the `\citep` command excect that it doesn't enclose the result in parentheses.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{flexner_medical_1910,
    Author = {Flexner, Abraham},
    Number = {4},
    Publisher = {Carnegie Foundation for the Advancement of Teaching},
    Title = {Medical education in the United States and Canada: a report to the Carnegie Foundation for the Advancement of Teaching},
    Year = {1910}
}
@book{flexner_medical_1912,
    Author = {Flexner, Abraham},
    Number = {6},
    Publisher = {Carnegie Foundation for the Advancement of Teaching},
    Title = {Medical education in Europe: a report to the Carnegie Foundation for the Advancement of Teaching},
    Year = {1912}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{document}
\citep{flexner_medical_1910,flexner_medical_1912}

(\citealp{flexner_medical_1910}; \citealp{flexner_medical_1912})
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```